# C# - How to call a string array from a void method to the main class

Tags: c#, arrays, oop

i have a string array called `movieNames` which is in a void class called `movieList` , now im able to call the `movieList` method in my mainClass but i have issues to get a refrence of `movieNames` array

```
using System;
class Arrays
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Arrays arr = new Arrays();
        arr.movieList();
        Random random = new Random();
        var random1 = random.Next(movieNames.Length); // as u can see i want to get one movie from the list and want to print in console
        Console.WriteLine( movieNames[random1]);


    }
    public void movieList()
    {
       
        string[] movieNames = new string[118];
        movieNames[0] = "The Lunchbox";
        movieNames[1] = "Sholay";
        movieNames[2] = "3 Idiots";
        movieNames[3] = "PK";
        movieNames[4] = "Dangal";
        movieNames[5] = "Andaz Apna Apna";
        movieNames[6] = "Munna Bhai M.B.B.S.";
        movieNames[7] = "Lagaan: Once Upon a Time in India";
        movieNames[8] = "Black Friday";
        movieNames[9] = "Kabhi Khushi Kabhie Gham";
        movieNames[10] = "Rang De Basanti";
        movieNames[11] = "Dilwale Dulhania Le Jayenge";
        movieNames[12] = "Chak de! India";
        movieNames[13] = "Taare Zameen Par";
        movieNames[14] = "Gangs of Wasseypur";
        movieNames[15] = "Parinda";
        movieNames[16] = "Mother India";
        movieNames[17] = "Drishyam";
        movieNames[18] = "Satya";
        movieNames[19] = "Deewaar";
        movieNames[20] = "Nayakan";
        movieNames[21] = "Kai Po Che!";
        movieNames[22] = "Dostana";
        movieNames[23] = "Munna Bhai M.B.B.S.";
        movieNames[24] = "Omkara";
        movieNames[25] = "Parinda";
        movieNames[26] = "Rang De Basanti";
        movieNames[27] = "Rockstar";
        movieNames[28] = "Sholay";
        movieNames[29] = "Taare Zameen Par";
        movieNames[30] = "The Lunchbox";
        movieNames[31] = "3 Idiots";
        movieNames[32] = "Dangal";
        movieNames[33] = "Andaz Apna Apna";
        movieNames[34] = "Munna Bhai M.B.B.S.";
        movieNames[35] = "Lagaan: Once Upon a Time in India";
        movieNames[36] = "Black Friday";
        movieNames[37] = "Kabhi Khushi Kabhie Gham";
        movieNames[38] = "Rang De Basanti";
        movieNames[39] = "Dilwale Dulhania Le Jayenge";
        movieNames[40] = "Chak de! India";
        movieNames[41] = "Taare Zameen Par";
        movieNames[42] = "Gangs of Wasseypur";
        movieNames[43] = "Parinda";
        movieNames[44] = "Mother India";
        movieNames[45] = "Drishyam";
        movieNames[46] = "Satya";
        movieNames[47] = "Deewaar";
        movieNames[48] = "Nayakan";
        movieNames[49] = "Kai Po Che!";
        movieNames[50] = "Dostana";
        movieNames[51] = "Munna Bhai M.B.B.S.";
        movieNames[52] = "Omkara";
        movieNames[53] = "Parinda";
        movieNames[54] = "Rang De Basanti";
        movieNames[55] = "Rockstar";
        movieNames[56] = "Sholay";
        movieNames[57] = "Taare Zameen Par";
        movieNames[58] = "The Lunchbox";
        movieNames[59] = "3 Idiots";
        movieNames[60] = "Dangal";
        movieNames[61] = "Andaz Apna Apna";
        movieNames[62] = "Munna Bhai M.B.B.S.";
        movieNames[63] = "Lagaan: Once Upon a Time in India";
        movieNames[64] = "Black Friday";
        movieNames[65] = "Kabhi Khushi Kabhie Gham";
        movieNames[66] = "Rang De Basanti";
        movieNames[67] = "Dilwale Dulhania Le Jayenge";
        movieNames[68] = "Chak de! India";
        movieNames[69] = "Taare Zameen Par";
        movieNames[70] = "Gangs of Wasseypur";
        movieNames[71] = "Parinda";
        movieNames[72] = "Mother India";
        movieNames[73] = "Drishyam";
        movieNames[74] = "Satya";
        movieNames[75] = "Deewaar";
        movieNames[76] = "Nayakan";
        movieNames[77] = "Kai Po Che!";
        movieNames[78] = "Dostana";
        movieNames[79] = "Munna Bhai M.B.B.S.";
        movieNames[80] = "Omkara";
        movieNames[81] = "Parinda";
        movieNames[82] = "Rang De Basanti";
        movieNames[83] = "Rockstar";
        movieNames[84] = "Sholay";
        movieNames[85] = "Taare Zameen Par";
        movieNames[86] = "The Lunchbox";
        movieNames[87] = "3 Idiots";
        movieNames[88] = "Dangal";
        movieNames[89] = "Andaz Apna Apna";
        movieNames[90] = "Munna Bhai M.B.B.S.";
        movieNames[91] = "Lagaan: Once Upon a Time in India";
        movieNames[92] = "Black Friday";
        movieNames[93] = "Kabhi Khushi Kabhie Gham";
        movieNames[94] = "Rang De Basanti";
        movieNames[95] = "Dilwale Dulhania Le Jayenge";
        movieNames[96] = "Chak de! India";
        movieNames[97] = "Taare Zameen Par";
        movieNames[98] = "Gangs of Wasseypur";
        movieNames[99] = "Parinda";
        movieNames[100] = "Mother India";
        movieNames[101] = "Drishyam";
        movieNames[102] = "Satya";
        movieNames[103] = "Deewaar";
        movieNames[104] = "Nayakan";
        movieNames[105] = "Kai Po Che!";
        movieNames[106] = "Dostana";
        movieNames[107] = "Munna Bhai M.B.B.S.";
        movieNames[108] = "Omkara";
        movieNames[109] = "Parinda";
        movieNames[110] = "Rang De Basanti";
        movieNames[111] = "Rockstar";
        movieNames[112] = "Sholay";
        movieNames[113] = "Taare Zameen Par";
        movieNames[114] = "The Lunchbox";
        movieNames[115] = "3 Idiots";
        movieNames[116] = "Dangal";
        movieNames[117] = "Andaz Apna Apna";

        
    }
}
```

Comment: So, there's no such thing as a void class. You have a class called "Arrays" and two functions that both return nothing (void).
If you want access to your movie names array, you'd have to return it from your "movieList" function and store it in a variable. 
Or you could call it in the constructor and read is as in instance variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need:

- use `return` in your method `movieList()` method
- set return type to `string[]`, not `void`

So code would look like this:

```
public string[] movieList()
{
   // the other code is omitted for the brevity
   return movieNames;
}
```

Or complete code:

```
public static void Main()
{
    string[] movieList = MovieList();
    Random random = new Random();
    var random1 = random.Next(movieList.Length);
    Console.WriteLine(movieList[random1]);
}


static string[] MovieList()
{
    string[] movieNames = new string[118];
    movieNames[0] = "The Lunchbox";
    movieNames[1] = "Sholay";
    movieNames[2] = "3 Idiots";

    // the other code is omitted for the brevity

    return movieNames;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To start, these are *methods*, not *classes*.  Terminology is important as you research problems, otherwise you're not looking for the right things.

As for the problem itself... `movieNames` is a *local variable* to the `movieList` method.  So it only exists within that method.  If you want the code which called that method to be able to observe it, return it from the method.  Change the return type:

```
public string[] movieList()
```

And return the array at the end of the method:

```
return movieNames;
```

Then the calling code can observe the returned result from the method (storing the result in its own local variable):

```
var movieNames = arr.movieList();
```

Answer (score 0):

You must return the array in your method MovieList and then, call it from Main.
David's answer is correct

Answer (score 0):

I suggest making MovieList into a property. I also suggest making it a list instead of an array.

Example:

```
public List<string> MovieTitles { get {
        List<string> output = new List<string>();
        output.Add("The Lunchbox");
        output.Add("Sholay");
        output.Add("3 Idiots");
        // etc
        return output;
    } }
```

Now you are able to call Array.MovieTitles and return a list of all your movies.

You shouldn't include the datatype in a variable's name. So MovieList should be renamed just Movies or MovieTitles.